# how do I get event label and event category parameters from event click in google analytics 4?

Tags: google-analytics, report, google-analytics-4, custom-events

I send event_label and event_category parameters in the click event and I can see this data in the Realtime section, but I am not able to see this information in engagement nor in reports.

So, my question is, if this data is getting stored or I lose this data?, Is there a way to retrieve the historical data?

This is the way I send the parameters with the click event

```
window.gtag("event", 'click', {
    event_category: category,
    event_label: label,
  });
```

I already create a custom dimension for event_label but I have to wait around 48 hours to be able to use it in reports and see if I have the historical data

Comment: If you have already created the custom dimension, that should be enough. Just check back in a couple days to see if the data is coming over the way it should. And also create the category dimension so you don't have to wait too much longer for your data.

Answer (score 2):

Universal analytics is completely diffrent then GA4.

Events in UA by default would record

[image]

by the actual call themself

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

Ga4 does not offer this same support.

If you want event_category and event_label in GA4 you will need to define them as custom dimensions and then set them yourself.  This is not something that will work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are talking about GA4 and Not Universal, so you have to create these variables as custom dimensions in your analytics.google profile, and it takes **48 hours** to get effected, before this time, you may get the result value as not set.
Remember, once created a custom dimension it is not possible to change the **Event parameter**.
[image: Look at this photo]

Then select "**Create custom dimensions**"
and enter the info

[image]